# Displaying single field across multiple layouts/tables

Tags: relational-database, filemaker

I have a Filemaker pro database (FM14) in which I have several tables.  The main table has a field called "species" and all descriptive details about each species.  The other tables are "photos", "regions" and so on.
In my layouts, I have my buttons on top navigation that trigger each layout based on that respective table.  Pretty standard stuff.

However, I would like to have the field "species" be on each of the layouts, so I can see which species I am working on.

I am struggling on, what is probably a very basic task.

Thanks

Comment: If your tables are related (and it sounds like they *should* be related by matching `SpeciesID`), you can simply place the `Species` field from the parent table on the layouts of your child tables. Make it non-enterable, to prevent accidental modification.

Comment: That is what I thought and exactly how it is set up.  I tried something by adding the species field to the other tables.  This allows the correct data to be displayed, but it is not "synced".  If I have species "A" on one layout, I go to another layout and species "B" details are displayed.  If i scroll thru the species, I can get to species "A".  That leads me to believe I might need some kind of script to "push" the details of species "A" across all layouts.  Is this the correct path?  Any idea what this needs to be?

Comment: I am afraid you lost me at this point. Also, your question seems to be off-topic for SO. I suggest you join one of the forums dedicated to FileMaker, where this can be discussed in detail.

Comment: OK, thanks for your effort

Comment: Let me try one last time.  The data is correct on all layouts (tables).  The issue is each time I go to a different layout (table), I need to search for that same species again.  I would like to have it so that when I am on a species in one layout, ALL layouts displays the SAME species so that when I change layouts, it always displays the species I am researching.  Does this help?

Comment: Not really. It sounds like you want to use the `Go to Related Record` script step, when you move from the parent Species table to one of the child tables. That will establish a found set containing all and only the children of the current species in the target layout. But really, I am reaching here.

Comment: Note that in any case, every photo, region etc. will display the data from its parent record, as determined by the relationship.